# post request in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to do this thing in windows phone 8.1 please suggest how to do.I have tried httpclient but didn't achieve the same result please suggest me something

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient web = new WebClient();
        web.Headers["content-type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string arg = "id=" + newone.Text;
        // var postdata =js
        string arg1 = "id=" + newone.Text;
        //web.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://terasol.in/hoo/test.php/?id=&ncuavfvlqfd"), "GET");
        web.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://terasol.in/hoo/test.php"), "POST", arg1);
        web.UploadStringCompleted += web_uploadstringcomplete;

    }
    void web_uploadstringcomplete(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result);

    }
```

thank you

Comment: Without me going to write the same code and testing for myself, could you please elaborate on what is different in the results, what is not happening that should be happening?

Comment: as in windows phone 8 all the methods like webclient or the related one are not present so what things can i used in 8.1 phone app in c#

Comment: Have you tried using HttpClient? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298639

Comment: i have try but didn't get the result

Comment: i want to post string say string arg="id="+sometext to get response from the php file

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: http://monkeyweekend.com/2014-10-23/how-to-send-text-json-or-files-using-httpclient-postasync/

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample code, and running it,
using the following code, I get the same value returned.

```
        private static void Button_Click2(string id)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://terasol.in/");
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("id", id)
        });
            var result = client.PostAsync("/hoo/test.php", content).Result;
            string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
        }

    }
```